# Replacing the values inside the value of a dictionary

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary, nested

1.I have a dataframe **Input:**

```
emp data
pp  ab
qq  bc
rr  cs
ss  dp
```

dictionary:

```
df_r.to_dict('dict')
```

2.I have another dataframe with name having string values:

```
ID name
1  ['u']['s']
2  ['v']['ab']
3  ['w']['dp']
4  ['x']['t']
```

dictionary :

```
df.to_dict('dict')
```

**Expected result** : I want to replace the value of name as per data's emp value

```
ID name
1  ['u']['s']
2  ['v']['pp']
3  ['w']['ss']
4  ['x']['t']
```

Code: I tried

```
mapper = dict(df_r[["data", "emp"]].values)
mapper
df.name = df.name.replace(mapper).values
df
```

**issue:** not doing any replacing of values. The dataframe remains unaffected.

Answer (score 1):

## Transform the first Dataframe to `dict` then use it to update the second Dataframe. Steps:

## Dataframes:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame([['pp', 'ab'], 
                    ['qq','bc'],
                    ['rr', 'cs'],
                    ['ss', 'dp']],
                   columns=['emp', 'data'])

df2 = pd.DataFrame([['u', 's'],
                   ['v', 'ab'],
                   ['w', 'dp'],
                   ['x', 't']],
                   columns=['ID', 'name'])
```

## Get dictionary from df1 where *data* as `keys`, *emp* as `values`:

Make data as index in the `Dataframe` then transforme into `dict`

```
df1_dict = df1.set_index('data').to_dict()['emp']
```

## Replace values in of name column of df2

```
df2['name'] = df2['name'].replace(df1_dict)
```

output:

```
  ID name
0  u    s
1  v   pp
2  w   ss
3  x    t
```

Comment: my second dataframe has string as value, so its not able to parse into it.

Comment: should I convert the string into list before this ?